# What are possible reasons for positive include angle (camber) on my 2002 Honda Civic?

Tags: civic, alignment, camber

I have a 2002 Honda Civic Hatchback (Make in UK, the body looks like the Civic SI in the States). Both the shocks and the lower arms have been replaced. I can see how the lower arms being too short could cause positive camber.

Are there other problems that could cause positive camber?

For example, I'm guessing that a strut assembly being too long could cause this problem. Is this a possible?

---

This is a more general question that is related to my specific question here:
[The wrong control arm for my 2002 Honda Civic?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/75140/the-wrong-control-arm-for-my-2002-honda-civic)

Comment: if it was aligned with old lower control arm, it will need re-aligned after replacement.

Comment: What makes you think you have positive camber?  Do you have measurements to prove it?  If so, please share them.

Comment: @Moab I performed an alignment after replacing the arms.

Comment: @HandyHowie This question assumes that there is a problem with postive caster (aka the included angle)

Comment: @krumpelstiltskin then they did it wrong.

Comment: @Moab they said that they have no way of adjusting camber and castor on the Civic.

Comment: @krumpelstiltskin the camber is not adjustable in a stock configuration. You might be able to purchase an adjustable shock mount or adjustable control arm to bring it into spec. There are other options too but as to why it's off...You didn't post by how much but suspension components can sag overtime or simply wear out causing a misalignment. I know you've replaced the shock and lower arms but these components may not be an EXACT replica of the original and other components might still need replacement. Also, the shock tower is often welded when the vehicle is made to set the camber. And

Comment: as such might not be a perfect alignment with replacement parts

Comment: @GabeWisneski Thanks for the advice. I've bought some camber bolts that I will use as a last resort. I'm going to have a look at the strut mounts and may replace them.